# How to set an exact repeating alarm on API 19 (kitkat)?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Starting from API 19, `setRepeating()` works the same way as `setInexactRepeating()`.
 What's the new way of setting an exact repeating alarm?

I.e. What's the API 19 version of the good old `setRepeating()`? Could you please provide an example for setting an alarm at 7:30 every morning (repeating daily) on KitKat?

Comment: there is a sample in the docs

Comment: @Raghunandan I read every single word on this article before asking: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html Could you please post a link to an example?

Comment: do you see the download sample on the top right of the page??

Comment: @Raghunandan Have you read the sample? In line 98 of `SampleAlarmReceiver.java`, they use `alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't exist, unfortunately. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times **then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above**. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

In short, if you need exact repeating alams, you can create an alarm with `setExact()`, but you'll need to handle the "repeating" part manually.

Comment: Do you have a code which handles the repeating part?

Comment: so, how to handle the repeating part?