# Work Around for setExact Repeating to set a Repeating alarm

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. The problem is when i use setRepeating with AlarmManager the repeatation of alarm works fine but the pending intent is not fired at correct time. It's a little late or fast.
But when i use setExact the pending intent fires at the exact time but setExact cannot be repeated. 
So Is there any workaround to make repeating alarm using setExact?
Thank you !

Comment: You can use setExact and from the receiver just call setExact  again. In this way , the alarm will be repeating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set exact, repeating alarms in Android 4.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959511/how-can-i-set-exact-repeating-alarms-in-android-4-4)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple - on the Task that is triggered on your exact time - re-setup the next exact alarm.