# Notification doesn't show up

Tags: android, alarmmanager, notificationmanager

I was trying to make an alarm which show notification everyday at 8:00 AM. But it didn't show up at all. Then I tried to make a button to make it show notification after 5 seconds. I tried this code

> AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        createNotification(context, "8A.M activity","It's time for breakfast!","Alert");
    }
    public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText,String msgAlert){
        PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,new Intent(context, MainActivity.class),0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_2424)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setTicker(msgAlert)
                .setContentText(msgText);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button nof
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nof = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNoftification);


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , AlarmReceiver.class);
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,1,myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));  //set repeating every 24 hours

        nof.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;
                Intent alertIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
                AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alertTime,PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,1,alertIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
                //alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,1,myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));  //set repeating every 24 hours
            }
        });
```

I already added permission in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

Comment: Did you include your `AlarmReceiver` class in Manifest as receiver?

Comment: oh thank you, sir :D

Comment: The notification finally work now. But the code about set it at 8AM, It show up at 8:03 for some reason

Comment: Maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/24298650/6272369

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your AlarmReceiver class in AndroidManifest as receiver inside of `<application />` tag.

```
<receiver android:name=".Alarms.AlarmReceiver"/>
```